# Understanding the proof of Proposition 3.1.2 and 3.1.4 of Tian's Lectures of Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

$\def\O{\mathcal O}\def\N{\operatorname N}\def\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}\def\Q{\mathbb Q}\def\Z{\mathbb Z}$Let $K$ be a number field and $\O_K$ be its ring of integers. The norm $\N(I)$ of an ideal $I\neq 0$ of $\O_K$ is defined by $N(I)=|\O_K/I|=[\O_K\colon I]$. In Tian's [note](http://www.mcm.ac.cn/faculty/tianyichao/201409/W020140919372982540194.pdf) of algebraic number theory, I find two propositions (Proposition 3.12 and 3.14 in page 27 and 28) of norms difficult to understand, especially their proofs, which state as follows.

> **Proposition 3.12** If $I=(x)$ for some $x\in\O_K$, then $\N(I)=|\N_{K/\Q}(x)|$.
>   *Proof.* Let $(α_1,\cdots,α_n)$ be a $\Z-basis$ of $\O_K$. There exists a matrix $C\in M_{n\times n}(\Z)$ such that $$(xα_1,\cdots,xα_n)=(α_1,\cdots,α_n)C.$$ It follows that $$\N(I)=[\O_K\colon I]=[\sum_i\Zα_i\colon\sum_i\Z xα_i]\color{red}{=}|\det(C)|.$$

And

> **Proposition 3.14** We have $N(\delta_K)=|\Delta_K|$.
>   *Proof*. Let $(α_1,\cdots,α_n)$ be a $\Z$-basis of $\O_K$, and $(α_1^\vee,\cdots,α_n^\vee)$ be its dual nasis w.r.t $\tr_{K/\Q}$. Then $\delta_K^{-1}=\oplus_i\Zα_i^\vee$ and $α_i=\sum_j\tr_{K/\Q}(α_iα_j)a_j\vee$. Therefore $$|\Delta_K|=|\det(\tr_{K/\Q}(α_iα_j))|\color{red}{=}[\bigoplus_i\Zα_i^\vee\colon\bigoplus_i\Zα_i]=[\delta_K^{-1}\colon\O_K]\color{red}{=}[\O_K\colon\delta_K]=\N(\delta_K).$$

Here the absolute different $\delta_K$ of $K$ is defined by $(\delta_K^{-1})^{-1}$, where $\delta_K^{-1}=\{x\in K\mid\tr_{K/\Q}(xy)\in Z,\forall y\in\O_K\}$ is a fractional ideal containing $\O_K$.

My question is about these red equal signs. For the first two, it seems that $|\det(C)|=[\bigoplus_i \Z\beta_i\colon \bigoplus_i\Z\gamma_i]$ if $\beta_i, \gamma_i\in K$ are $\Z$-independent and $\bigoplus_i \Z\beta_i\supset \bigoplus_i\Z\gamma_i$ with $C$ being the transition matrix? For the last equal sign, how can I see $[\delta_K^{-1}\colon\O_K]=[\O_K\colon\delta_K]$? Thanks!

Comment: The first two are straightforward if you picture the index as volume ratio of two fundamental domains of some lattices. Given an $n\times n$ invertible matrix $A$, consider the integer lattice generated by columns of $A$, then $|\det A|$ is the volume of a fundamental domain of $A$ (if we assign $[0,1]^n$ has volume 1).

Comment: For third red equal sign, it is an application of multiplicativity of norm: if $I\subset J$ be two fractional ideals, then $$[J : I] = N(I)/N(J)$$ while for any other fractional ideal $I'$: $$[JI' : II'] = N(II')/N(JI') = N(I)/N(J) = [J : I]$$

Comment: @pisco thanks a lot for your answer, I think I got it now.